# From...to - how to use articles?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

Is this part of a sentence correct?

> ...the flow of electrons from atom to atom and from molecule to molecule...

Or I should use articles?

> from an atom to another one and from a molecule to another molecule.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say *from **one** thing to another*. But, that aside, both versions are commonly used. You could also simply say *between* atoms, if you wanted the most simplistic construction. In short, there is no rule, it's just what feels best to you.

Comment: Jason, thank you!